# How to implement a menuitem click listener inside a fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-fragmentactivity

I have MenuItems in the ActionBar and I am using Fragments inside ViewPager. Now I would like to handle onMenuItemClickListener event inside my fragment. It works fine inside Main Activity. But not inside Fragments. And also it doesn't fetch any error.

Here is the methods that I tried. Both works fine inside Activity.

First method:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.grid_view);
    item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
           Log.v("test","dfsfdsfasd");
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Second Method:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.grid_view:
    {
        Log.v("Log:","grid_view item pressed");
        return true;
    }

    case R.id.list_view:
    {
        Log.v("Log:","list_view item pressed");
        return true;
    }
    default:
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any help on how to achieve this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by using onPrepareOptionsMenu method.